# Check boxes in specific state

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of checkboxes of major cities in the US.  I have created a drop menu to select a state.  When the user clicks the submit button I want to selected all the checkboxes for that specific state.  I am already using a dynamic id for each check, I was thinking I could identify them with the title attribute.

Is there a way to select all "New York State" with regular javascript not jquery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

neojakey

EDIT

I was thinking along these lines

```
function SelectState(StateAbbr)
{
     var f = document.frmChangeMemberPaid;
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('LocalPageID');
     for(var i in checkboxes)
     {
          if(checkboxes[i].attributes[1].name == StateAbbr)
          {
               checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use function `getElementsByTagName` to get all inputs, filter out all checkboxes and then check only those that match your criteria:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i=0, count = inputs.length; i < count; i++) {
    var node = inputs.item(i);
    if (node.type === "checkbox") {
        if (node.title === "New York State") {
            node.checked = true;
        } else {
            // uncheck other checkboxes in case they are already checked
            node.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly Andrei..  Cant thank you enough, great job..!

Answer (score 0):

Use classes to mark inputs:

```
<table id="cities" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Miami, FL
            <input type="checkbox" value="Miami" class="FL" />
        </td>
        <td>
            New York City, NY
            <input type="checkbox" value="New York City" class="NY" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tampa, FL
            <input type="checkbox" value="Tampa" class="FL" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Buffalo, NY
            <input type="checkbox" value="Buffalo" class="NY" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="states">
     <option value="FL">FL</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var cities = document.getElementById('cities'),
    states = document.getElementById('states');

    function checkCitiesOf(state) {
        inputs = cities.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
            inputs[i].checked = inputs[i].className == state;       
        }
    }

    states.onchange = function() {
        checkCitiesOf(this.value);
    };
</script>
```

​
​

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/PvLVj/)**​